# Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Prove that if $|E| \ge 2kn$ Then $G$ Contains a path of at least length $k$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Prove that if $|E| \ge 2kn$ then $G$ Contains a path of at least length $k$

I know the relationship between the number of edges and the sum of degrees Of the vertices. I also know that every graph contains a path at least the length of the minimum degree of $G$

I tried just using those relationships and coming to a conclusion, but I am stuck. I got to a point where i could show that $k \le n^2$ but wasnt sure if that helped me

Comment: Did you try induction on $k$?

Comment: Well, $k\le n^2$ is not really a good bound. In fact, $k\le \frac{n-1}{4}$ since $|E|\le \binom{n}{2}$

Comment: @cgss I did not. I dont know where to start to be honest

Comment: $G$ isn't necessarily connected. Can you show that we can wlog assume that it is? Graph connectivity is a nice tool.

Comment: @cgss well if k=0, we dont really care i think. If k=1 then we have that the number of edges is greater than or equal to 2n and then the average degree is greater than one which implies there exists a path? Is that valid logic? Sorry, I am just starting with Graph theory